# Internal cache lookup and store value not working

Tags: azure-api-management

I am using Azure APIM Developer tier. I am trying to store a value in internal cache but it is not working.

**Error message:** No appropriate cache found for provided policy configuration. Policy execution will be skipped.

I understand that internal cache is available by default in APIM Developer tier. Does this message mean that it is not configured properly or there can be some other issue?

**Policy** (showing on cache related policies)

```
<!-- Check if partner info has already been cached for this subscription key and fetch it into a variable. -->
<cache-lookup-value key="@((string)context.Variables["subscriptionKey"])" variable-name="partnerInfo" caching-type="internal"/>
:
:
<set-variable name="partnerInfo" value="@{
            var partnerAccountNumber = context.Variables["partnerAccountNumber"];
            var partnerRegion = context.Variables["partnerRegion"];
            var partnerType = context.Variables["partnerType"];

            return $"{partnerAccountNumber}:{partnerRegion}:{partnerType}";
        }"/>

<cache-store-value caching-type="internal" key="@((string)context.Variables["id"])" value="@((string)context.Variables["partnerInfo"])" duration="10000"/>
```

**Trace**

```
{
    "source": "cache-lookup-value",
    "timestamp": "2022-03-10T21:58:24.6068604Z",
    "elapsed": "00:00:00.0005265",
    "data": "No appropriate cache found for provided policy configuration. Policy execution will be skipped."
},
{
    "source": "cache-lookup-value",
    "timestamp": "2022-03-10T21:58:24.6068650Z",
    "elapsed": "00:00:00.0005312",
    "data": {
        "message": "Cache lookup resulted in a miss, variable will not be set.",
        "key": "2_7c486765553047aca4f1088c0e5b1b8e",
        "variableName": "partnerInfo"
        }
}
:
:
:
{
    "source": "set-variable",
    "timestamp": "2022-03-10T21:58:25.2051048Z",
    "elapsed": "00:00:00.5987711",
    "data": {
        "message": "Context variable was successfully set.",
        "name": "partnerInfo",
        "value": "674756756:EMEA:CUSTOMER"
        }
},
{
    "source": "cache-store-value",
    "timestamp": "2022-03-10T21:58:25.2051357Z",
    "elapsed": "00:00:00.5988023",
    "data": "No appropriate cache found for provided policy configuration. Policy execution will be skipped."
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just remembered that we're using *self-hosted* gateways. As per [documentation](https://gc-apim-dev1.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/f2bf959a-eb76-47f3-89f7-c7004533eccf/resourceGroups/rg-gc-uty-apim-dev/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/gc-apim-dev1?api-version=2021-01-01-preview), built-in caching is not available for this type of setup and one should use external caching mechanism.